# Como cambiar con Eloquent ORM todos los registros de un único campo en una consulta

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Quisiera hacer algo así con Eloquent:

```
UPDATE `perros` SET `raza` = "indeterminado" WHERE `raza` = "Lobo"
```

De manera que todos los registros del campo "raza" que coincidan con el valor "Lobo" automáticamente sean reescritos al valor "indeterminado".

Se como identificar todos los registros con valor "Lobo" pero no se como actualizarlos todos a la vez.

```
Perros::where("raza","Lobo")->get()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para esto se utiliza el método Update de Eloquent

```
Perros::where('raza', 'Lobo')->update(['raza' => 'indeterminado']);
```